# Erase paint drawn on canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, paint

I am trying to develop a finger paint type app using a demo, everything is fine except the erasing function.

My MainActivity is,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

//custom drawing view
private DrawingView drawView;
//buttons
private ImageButton currPaint, drawBtn, eraseBtn, newBtn, saveBtn;
//sizes
private float smallBrush, mediumBrush, largeBrush;
//to save image
Bitmap saveImageBM;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //get drawing view
    drawView = (DrawingView)findViewById(R.id.drawing);

    //get the palette and first color button
    LinearLayout paintLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.paint_colors);
    currPaint = (ImageButton)paintLayout.getChildAt(0);

           currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed));

    //sizes from dimensions
    smallBrush = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.small_size);
    mediumBrush = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.medium_size);
    largeBrush = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.large_size);

    //draw button
    drawBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.draw_btn);
    drawBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    //set initial size
    drawView.setBrushSize(smallBrush);

    //erase button
    eraseBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.erase_btn);
    eraseBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    //new button
    newBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.new_btn);
    newBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    //save button
    saveBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

//user clicked paint
public void paintClicked(View view){
    //use chosen color

    //set erase false
    drawView.setErase(false);
    drawView.setBrushSize(drawView.getLastBrushSize());

    if(view!=currPaint){
        ImageButton imgView = (ImageButton)view;
        String color = view.getTag().toString();
        drawView.setColor(color);
        //update ui
        imgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed));
        currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint));
        currPaint=(ImageButton)view;
    }
}

//called when draw_btn clicked
@Override
public void onClick(View view){

    if(view.getId()==R.id.draw_btn){
        //draw button clicked
        final Dialog brushDialog = new Dialog(this);
        brushDialog.setTitle("Brush size:");
        brushDialog.setContentView(R.layout.brush_chooser);
        //listen for clicks on size buttons
        ImageButton smallBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.small_brush);
        smallBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setErase(false);
                drawView.setBrushSize(smallBrush);
                drawView.setLastBrushSize(smallBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ImageButton mediumBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.medium_brush);
        mediumBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setErase(false);
                drawView.setBrushSize(mediumBrush);
                drawView.setLastBrushSize(mediumBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ImageButton largeBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.large_brush);
        largeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setErase(false);
                drawView.setBrushSize(largeBrush);
                drawView.setLastBrushSize(largeBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        //show and wait for user interaction
        brushDialog.show();
    }
    else if(view.getId()==R.id.erase_btn){
        //switch to erase - choose size
        final Dialog brushDialog = new Dialog(this);
        brushDialog.setTitle("Eraser size:");
        brushDialog.setContentView(R.layout.brush_chooser);
        //size buttons
        ImageButton smallBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.small_brush);
        smallBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setErase(true);
                drawView.setBrushSize(smallBrush);
                /*drawView.clearPoints();*/
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ImageButton mediumBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.medium_brush);
        mediumBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setErase(true);
                drawView.setBrushSize(mediumBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ImageButton largeBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.large_brush);
        largeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setErase(true);
                drawView.setBrushSize(largeBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        brushDialog.show();
    }
    else if(view.getId()==R.id.new_btn){
        //new button
        AlertDialog.Builder newDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        newDialog.setTitle("New drawing");
        newDialog.setMessage("Start new drawing (you will lose the current drawing)?");
        newDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                drawView.startNew();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        newDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        newDialog.show();
    }
    else if(view.getId()==R.id.save_btn){
        //save drawing
        AlertDialog.Builder saveDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        saveDialog.setTitle("Save drawing");
        saveDialog.setMessage("Save drawing to device Gallery?");
        saveDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                //save drawing
                drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                //attempt to save
                saveImageBM = drawView.getDrawingCache();
                Log.i("image", " "+saveImageBM);
                if (saveImageBM!=null) {
                    saveImage(saveImageBM); 
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image is not saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


                /*String imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                        getContentResolver(), drawView.getDrawingCache(),
                        UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".png", "drawing");*/
                //feedback
                /*if(imgSaved!=null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Drawing saved to Gallery!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oops! Image could not be saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }*/
                drawView.destroyDrawingCache();
            }
        });
        saveDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        saveDialog.show();
    }
}

private void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    // save to folder in sd card
    try 
    {
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "winoria");
        if(!imagesFolder.exists())
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();

        StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
        long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() * (long)stat.getBlockCount();
        long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / 1048576;

        if(megAvailable>20)
        {           
            String fileName=""+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
            File output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
            OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(output);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);         
            /*Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "winoria/"+fileName);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);            
            sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);     */
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
        }           
        else 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No enough space available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        

     } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SlideShowFragement:"+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SlideShowFragement:"+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
    }
```

And my View is,

```
public class DrawingView extends View {

//drawing path
private Path drawPath;
//drawing and canvas paint
private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
//initial color
private int paintColor = 0xFF660000;
//canvas
private Canvas drawCanvas;
//canvas bitmap
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
//brush sizes
private float brushSize, lastBrushSize;
//erase flag
private boolean erase=false;

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    setupDrawing();
}

//setup drawing
private void setupDrawing(){

    //prepare for drawing and setup paint stroke properties
    brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.small_size);
    lastBrushSize = brushSize;
    drawPath = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();

    //set initial color
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);

    //set initial path properties

    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);//we have two options Fill and STROKE
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}

//will be called when the custom View is assigned a size:
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}

//draw the view - will be called after touch event
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
}

//register user touches as drawing action
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    //retrieve the X and Y positions of the user touch:
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();

    //respond to down, move and up events
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN://A pressed gesture has started, the motion contains the initial starting location.
        drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);//Set the beginning of the next contour to the point (x,y)

        //extra code for erase
        //mPaint.setStrokeWidth(25);
        /*if(erase){
        drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        drawCanvas.drawCircle(touchX, touchY, 10, drawPaint);
        }
        invalidate();*/
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE://A change has happened during a press gesture (between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP).
        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);//Add a line from the last point to the specified point (x,y)

        //extra code for erase
        /*if(erase){
            drawCanvas.drawCircle(touchX, touchY, 20, drawPaint);
        }
        else{
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
        }invalidate();*/

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP://A pressed gesture has finished, the motion contains the final release location as well as any intermediate points since the last down or move event
        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);//Draw the specified path using the specified paint.
        //drawPath.rewind();
        drawPath.reset();
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }
    //redraw
    invalidate();
    return true;

}

//update color
public void setColor(String newColor){
    invalidate();
    paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
}

//set brush size
public void setBrushSize(float newSize){
    float pixelAmount = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
            newSize, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    brushSize=pixelAmount;
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
}

//get and set last brush size
public void setLastBrushSize(float lastSize){
    lastBrushSize=lastSize;
}
public float getLastBrushSize(){
    return lastBrushSize;
}



//set erase true or false
public void setErase(boolean isErase){
    erase=isErase;
    if(erase){
        drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));
    } 
    else{
        drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
    }
}
//start new drawing
public void startNew(){
    drawCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    invalidate();
}
    }
```

Problem part is the setErase function, when i erase the paint it shows black shadow and I want to remove that so please suggest me how can I fix that.